# yii2 - add field to model without new tablefield

Tags: model, field, yii2

I want to add a field to a model, so it is displayed in index/update/create.

It should also be editable in update/create.

And after sendin/save from update/create I want work with the content of this field, calculate something and then write it with all the other fields (they have corresponding fields in DB) to database in a existing DB-field.

I can display a new field in index by adding in model (frontend/model/poi.php

```
public $tempVal = NULL;
```

and in rules in same file

```
[['tempVal'], 'string', 'max' => 64],
```

So all rows will have the same content in this field.
-> That's not what I want.

The field should have different content (say random number) in each row.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please show the model and the controller of POI

Answer (score 0):

Here is model and controller (not working)

/frontend/models/PoiCore.php

```
class PoiCore extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
public $tempVal = NULL;
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'poi_core';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['owner'], 'required'],
        [['owner'], 'integer'],
        [['poi_name'], 'string', 'max' => 64],
        [['tempVal'], 'string', 'max' => 64],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
        'owner' => Yii::t('app', 'Owner'),
        'poi_name' => Yii::t('app', 'Poi Name'),
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getPoiDetail()
{
    $data= $this->hasOne(PoiDetail::className(), ['poi_id' => 'id']);

    return $data;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 * @return PoiCoreQuery the active query used by this AR class.
 */
public static function find()
{
    $data= new PoiCoreQuery(get_called_class());
    return $data;
}
}
```

and controller

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use frontend\models\PoiCore;
use frontend\models\PoiSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * PoiController implements the CRUD actions for PoiCore model.
 */
class PoiController extends Controller
{
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * Lists all PoiCore models.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new PoiSearch();
  $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Displays a single PoiCore model.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionView($id)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Creates a new PoiCore model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new PoiCore();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Updates an existing PoiCore model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Deletes an existing PoiCore model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}

/**
 * Finds the PoiCore model based on its primary key value.
 * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return PoiCore the loaded model
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = PoiCore::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
}
```